# how to add link url in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

[image]

In image the problem while adding cart value to order insert, link will be make blank but in my cart item has E-book and Print Book type link. how can i add in order table also. suggest me?

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getProductId());
$rowTotal = $product->getPrice() * $product->getQty();   
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')  
->setStoreId($storeId)   
->setQuoteItemId(0)  
->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)  
->setProductId($product->getProductId())  
->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())  
->setQtyBackordered(NULL)   
->setTotalQtyOrdered($product->getQty())  
->setQtyOrdered($product->getQty())   
->setName($_product->getName())  
->setSku($_product->getSku())  
->setPrice($product->getPrice())  
->setBasePrice($product->getPrice())  
->setOriginalPrice($product->getPrice())  
->setRowTotal($rowTotal)  
->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to add it yourself; it should work out of the box. Here is a screenshot of my test environment;

[image]

So there aren't any actual links, but you can see a list of the products that have been purchased and how many times they are downloaded / how many times they can be downloaded (U = Unlimited).

The problem could be at multiple points. Start by looking at  `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml`

On line 56, you'll find

```
<?php foreach ($this->getLinks()->getPurchasedItems() as $_link): ?>
```

The fetching of these links is done in `Mage_Downloadable_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Items_Column_Downloadable_Name`

You'll see there it fetches the data from the tables `downloadable_link_purchased` and `downloadable_link_purchased_item`.

I suggest start looking in those tables to see whether there are even rows available for your order ID.

If there are, I think an extension in your shop might be trying to rewrite a part of this section and failing. Try disabling extensions that have something to do with the order grid and/or downloadable items.